# java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification Error

Tags: java

Whenever I try to remove one of my entities, the game gives me this error and I'm not sure why.

This is the method that creates the error:

```
public void render (Screen screen) {
    int xTile = 11;
    int yTile = 0;
    int scale = 1;

    screen.render (x, y, xTile + yTile * 32, colour, 0, scale);

    if (level.player != null) {
        int xd = level.player.x - x;
        int yd = level.player.y - y;
        if (xd * xd + yd * yd < 8 * 8) {
            Font.render("Pick up", screen, x - 18, y - 17, Colours.get(-1, -1, -1, 555), 1);
            if (item == true) {
                Font.render("It's true!", screen, x - 18, y - 17, Colours.get(-1, -1, -1, 555), 1);
                level.removeEntity(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the removeEntity method:

```
public void removeEntity(Entity entity) {
    entities.remove(entity);
}
```

Comment: What implementation-type is your `entities` ?

Comment: You're removing an element from a collection that you're currently iterating over. That can't be done, expect with some collection implementations, or by using the iterator's remove() method.

Comment: @JBNizet how do you know he is iterating a collection?

Comment: @nachokk: I suspect it from the exception origin posted in the question title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the rest of your code looks something like this:

```
for (Entity e : level.entities) {
    e.render();
}
```

That means somewhere, you'd be calling `level.entities.remove()` while iterating over `entities`, which results in a `ConcurrentModificationException` or a `CheckForComodificationError`.

One of the easier solutions is to keep a separate list of items to remove as one batch operation, after iteration is complete:

```
level.queueRemoveEntity(this);
// .. finish rendering all entities ..
level.entities.removeAll(level.queuedEntities);
level.queuedEntities.clear();
```